# Why do different Pythons functions act differently in VIsual Studio 2022 IDE for Python workload

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-2022

## **Dataframe.head() not showing anything in Editor while using Visual Studio 22 as Python IDE**

**Code Block 1**

```
with open('C:/kaggle/train.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row)
```

1. Above block of code shows all rows of a dataset when I run it by pressing F5
2. However when I paste it into the Python Interactive window I get the following error

```
>>> with open('C:/kaggle/train.csv') as csv_file:
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    with open('C:/kaggle/train.csv') as csv_file:
                                                 ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
>>>     csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>for row in csv_reader:
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    for row in csv_reader:
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>         print(row)
```

**Code Block 2**

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:/kaggle/train.csv")
df.head()
```

1. Above block of code does not display anything when I run it in the Editor. I am asked to *Press Any key* to continue
2. However when I paste it into the Python Interactive window it works perfectly

Why is this the case and what am I doing wrong?